Showing intersection of a plane in a 3d shape with Three.js
I tried to animate with Three.js to show the intersection plane on a 3d object. In this example, I have used a cone as an example for the 3d object in the following code:
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';

export const App = () => {
  const mountRef = useRef(null);
  const [planeAngle, setPlaneAngle] = useState(Math.PI / 4); // Initial angle in radians

  useEffect(() => {
    const width = 800;
    const height = 600;

    // Scene setup
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x000000);
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 1000);
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    mountRef.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // Cone
    const length = 2;
    const coneHeight = length * Math.SQRT2;
    const coneRadius = length / Math.SQRT2;
    const coneGeometry = new THREE.ConeGeometry(coneRadius, coneHeight, 32);
    const coneMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00, wireframe: true });
    const cone = new THREE.Mesh(coneGeometry, coneMaterial);
    cone.position.y = 0;
    scene.add(cone);

    // Plane
    const planeSize = length * Math.SQRT2;
    const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(planeSize, planeSize);
    const planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, side: THREE.DoubleSide, transparent: true, opacity: 0.5 });
    const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
    scene.add(plane);

    // Position camera
    camera.position.set(3, 3, 5);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

    // Animation
    const animate = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);

      // Set plane rotation based on planeAngle
      plane.rotation.set(planeAngle, 0, 0);

      // Keep plane centered
      plane.position.set(0, 0, 0);

      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    animate();

    // Cleanup
    return () => {
      mountRef.current.removeChild(renderer.domElement);
    };
  }, [planeAngle]);

  const handleAngleChange = (event) => {
    setPlaneAngle(parseFloat(event.target.value));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={mountRef}></div>
      <div style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: '10px', left: '10px', color: 'white' }}>
        Plane Angle: 
        <input 
          type="range"
          min="0"
          max={Math.PI / 2}
          step="0.01"
          value={planeAngle}
          onChange={handleAngleChange}
          style={{ width: '200px' }}
        />
        {(planeAngle * 180 / Math.PI).toFixed(2)}°
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

produced the following rendering:

However, this is not exactly what I was looking for, because I was looking to produce a rendering like this:

So I had tried a lot of approaches in making only the intersected plane within the 3d object to show and hide the parts of the plane outside of the 3d object, but many of them seemed to be too convoluted. Is there a simple and intuitive way to get the desired rendering without too much tinkering?


Is there a simple and intuitive way to get the desired rendering
without too much tinkering?

Yes.
Just create cone and create circular plane. Place the circular plane in the center of the cone. Then adjust the transformations. At first glance from your screenshots, I thought of using a clippingPlanes, but you most likely won't render the center of the plane. For more advanced techniques, you can experiment with custom shader and discard, but why do it, if you can achieve the result more easily in a simpler way...


<script type="importmap">
  {
"imports": {
  "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.166.0/build/three.module.js",
  "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.166.0/examples/jsm/"
}
  }
</script>

<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';


const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 20;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const group = new THREE.Group();

const coneRadius = 5;
const coneHeight = 10;

const coneGeometry = new THREE.ConeGeometry(coneRadius, coneHeight, 16);
const coneMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
color: 0x00ff00,
wireframe: true,
transparent: true,
opacity: 0.5,
side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
const coneMesh = new THREE.Mesh(coneGeometry, coneMaterial);

const planeRadius = coneRadius;
const planeGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(planeRadius, 32);
const planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
color: 0xff0000,
transparent: true,
opacity: 0.5,
side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
const planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);

planeMesh.position.set(0, coneHeight * -0.1, 0); 
planeMesh.scale.set(0.6, 0.6, 1);
planeMesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;

group.add(coneMesh);
group.add(planeMesh);

scene.add(group);

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.enabled = true;

let groupRotationSpeed = 0.005;
let groupRotationX = 0.2;
let groupRotationY = 0.1;
let groupRotationZ = 0.3;

function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

groupRotationX += groupRotationSpeed;
groupRotationY += groupRotationSpeed;
groupRotationZ += groupRotationSpeed;

group.rotation.set(groupRotationX, groupRotationY, groupRotationZ);

controls.update();
renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();

</script>




A generalization approach to this problem rather than creating custom solutions pertaining to specific intersected objects would be preferable

Could you explain more in your post, because it sounds to me very… abstract.

The cone was just an example of the 3d object so the intersection effect should work when the 3d object is swapped to a cube, or cuboid, or trapezoid, or tetrahedron. I've edited the post for clarity and emphasis.
